# Python Hexdump similar to Linux Hexdump

Tags: python, hex, binaryfiles, hexdump

I have a 1.5MB binary file. I am using this HEXDUMP module in python. https://pypi.org/project/hexdump/ .
When I dump the HEX **from python** the hex bytes are reversed i.e 1f03 080b etc. Is there a module in python that dumps the HEX same as linux ( cmd: hexdump filename )

Example of linux hex dump.

```
031f 0b08 0000 0567 00fd 0ff8 0004 0000
0000 0248 0001 06c8 00dc 0001 0004 0000
```

Python output

```
1F 03 08 0B 00 00 67 05  FD 00 F8 0F 04 00 00 00
00 00 48 02 01 00 C8 06  DC 00 01 00 04 00 00 00
```

thanks

Comment: What you call *linux hexdump* dumps 16 bit words in hexa on a little endian system. What you call Python output dumps bytes in hexa. The swapping does not occur on the Python output but on the linux hexdump one.

Comment: Thanks Serge for that information, How would I change the Python output to reflex the linux output ?

Comment: Can you add the commands that you used to generate these files in your question? Also, there doesn't seem to be a clear question above.

Comment: Ross the command is in the question and the question i think is clear, what do you not understand and i will expand.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import textwrap

def hdump(h):
  print(textwrap.fill(' '.join(list(('0'+hex(x)[2:])[-2:3] for x in h)),48))

hdump(os.urandom(256))
```

output:

```
50 18 6d 57 7c db 3e 85 e4 f9 3e f5 80 4b e4 bf
cd 66 e1 9f 90 34 cd 40 1a 79 76 d1 33 2a 7c c0
dc 73 1e 78 e2 69 5a eb b7 36 c7 76 08 e9 07 bd
ad 76 bf 44 52 82 c2 bf 0a 80 2e fc d8 f2 09 eb
d8 be 5f 10 cc 58 30 76 ff 83 18 c7 74 61 7c 5a
af 70 1f cc 29 d0 17 a4 94 14 d1 ef 99 a1 2f f3
ad 6a 58 3d c0 b2 6e 41 3c fe 8c 2f c3 cc 9b 2f
58 7e 13 eb ba 0f 61 58 80 b1 49 98 c6 f8 f4 01
a1 9f 43 73 ad be 26 8c ab 93 86 fd a0 90 d4 f1
a3 50 07 30 cf 08 2a 10 f4 81 70 29 7b 80 0e d4
3e 21 b2 d5 91 4d 7f 15 e6 ef f2 e4 dd 8d 74 86
47 ac 13 2d d4 cf 58 80 1b 8d 88 f1 a1 77 9b 8a
4e e5 1f 4c f9 92 70 83 8d c5 42 1a 52 aa f0 eb
10 b9 6c 4a 38 5d 30 7c ce 93 fb a7 d0 5d ab 22
cb 1e 1a 8e ce 08 5c 68 a4 fd 5c fd 00 52 c9 1c
47 11 6a 78 1b 55 07 33 0e be 85 1c 50 7d cb b0
```